# Assign the values in Map<Id, String> ,Where ID = ContactID and String = Case.Mobile_Number__C

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
Public Class CaseHandler{
    Public Static void conCaseDetail (List<Case> lstCases){
        //getting Data of Contact Id store in SET Collection
        Set<Id> conid = new Set<Id>();
        for(Case cs: lstCases){
            conid.add(cs.ContactId);
        }

        //SOQL for Fetching Record From a particular set Id.
        List<Contact> lstContact = [Select id,
                                   (Select id, Mobile_Number__c From Cases)
                                   From Contact Where Id In :conid];
        Map<Id, String> newMap = new Map<Id, String>();

        for(Contact cn :lstContact){
            newmap.put(cn.ContactId , --->here Issue**what to put<----);
        }
    }
}
```

Question is: In the Map Collection How to add Id as ContactId and String as Case field called Mobile Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a set and query again. You can do it by just iterating over cases as below -

```
Map<Id, String> newMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for(Case cs: lstCases){
    // If Mobile_Number__c is text field
    newmap.put(cs.ContactId, cs.Mobile_Number__c);
}
```

If Mobile_Number__c is not a text field then you can use `String.valueOf(Mobile_Number__c);`

And if you want to create `Map<Id, List<String>>`, then you can do something like this -

```
Map<Id, List<String>> newMap = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
for(Case cs: lstCases){
    // If Mobile_Number__c is text field
    if(!newMap.containsKey(cs.ContactId)) {
        newMap.put(cs.ContactId, new List<String>());
    }
    newmap.get(cs.ContactId).add(cs.Mobile_Number__c);
}
```

Comment: This way will be stored only the last `Mobile_Number__c` for each Contact. I.E. if you have 3 cases related to the same contact, you'll have just one entry in the map with the value of the last case.

Comment: Yes, and that is what is mentioned in the question. And, even if that is required, then there will be a very small update in the code.

Comment: Well, I don't think that Map<Id,List<String>> is the requirement here but still I have updated the answer to include that case also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could have multiple cases for a single contact, you should collect multiple Mobile Number for each Contact, so the map should either be a `Map<Id, List<String>> mapContactIdToMobileNumberList` or, if you need the case id too, a `Map<Id, Map<Id, String>> mapContactIdToMapCaseIdToMobileNumber`.
You should also add a WHERE clause to filter the query on Cases.
In the loop you just have to create a new instance of a list of string, put it into the map with the current id, then loop on Cases relationship to add the mobile phone to the list.
Therefore the loop would look like:

```java
List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT Id,
                            (SELECT Mobile_Number__c FROM Cases WHERE Mobile_Number__c != null)
                            FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conid];

Map<Id, List<String>> mapContactIdToMobileNumberList = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
for (Contact cn : lstContact) {
    List<String> mobileNumberList = new List<String>();
    mapContactIdToMobileNumberList.put(cn.Id, mobileNumberList);
    for (Case c : lstContact.Cases) {
        mobileNumberList.add(c.Mobile_Number__c);
    }
}
```

Please note that nested loop are not always *bad*. Indeed here you never iterate two times on the same record.